# 3d chart in .net control

Tags: .net, user-interface, charts

I have a 2 dimensional array of doubles I would like to display as a 3d mesh.  Are there any open source libraries that can do this as a .net control?

I'd like to choose between shaded and wireframe, be able to color based on elevation, and be able to rotate the view via mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a control on codeproject that might help you out.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/ntgraph3d_atl.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Super 2d/3d Graph Library seems to support all your requirements:

- Shaded/wireframe
- Color based on elevation
- Rotation
- Zoom

Take a look at [this sample](http://www.softwaresigloxxi.com/example52xyz-surface-databound-datagridview-new.html).

It's not open source, but it's cheap (99€) and it's royalty-free (so no distribution limits). Also you can get full source code for 299€.